# regex negate numbers

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex

Currently I have this regular expression to validate letters, dash and spaces.

```
/^[a-zA-Z-\s]*$/
```

Now, I am quite confused how can this be rewritten to have a rule that it will accept everything except numbers?

Comment: Be aware that it's safer to always put the dash at the start or end of a character class. Otherwise, it might be misinterpreted as a range indicator like in `a-z`. In your case, the meaning is obvious, but not all regex engines can handle this correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have anything except something, you need a negated character class

```
 [^\d]
```

A character class that starts with `^` is a negated class, `\d` is a predefined class that contains digits.

If you have really only digits you can shorten this further, there is also a predefined negation of `\d` that is `\D`

So `[^\d]` = `\D`

You may find [this link to a regex reference on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) useful

Comment: @BoyTanong I added a further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^\D*$/
```

`\D` matches any character that is not a digit.  The above expression matches any string that is comprised entirely of non-digits.

(This pattern matches "abc", does not match "123" or "ab2c".)

Answer (score 0):

just use `\D` that has the same meaning of `[^\d]`

```
/\D/
```